# Tax on cheques that are yet to be encashed

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india, check

I have a cheque issued with a date 20/01/2021 and validity of 3 months.
I forgot to encash it and now the cheque is expired. I want to know if I need to identify this as a source on income for the financial year 2020-2021.

I'm under Indian Tax system.

Comment: No encash -> no income -> no tax...